# How to customize Tableau Dashboard to read and display corresponding values?

Tags: userform, tableau-api

I need your help in customizing my tableau dashboard.
My data table in excel looks like this: 
                   Year  Actual  Target

```
               2012     12      15

               2013     20      23

               2014     23      25
```

In my tableau dashboard, I want the user to select/input just the year and in return, I want to display the corresponding values. For example, if the user selects Year=2013, then I want to display the actual(20) and Target(23) values to the corresponding year in Tableau Dashboard.
So far, I could only manage to get the year in the input field, but unable to return values corresponding to it.

In short, this is what I want to achieve.

[image]

Comment: hello.. thank you all for viewing my question. I would like to know whether the above requirement is possible or not. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. You drag the [Actual] and [Target] fields, and drop them on Rows. Then select both, right-click and select discrete. This way Tableau will understand you don't want a continuous graphic, rather you want to display discrete values.

I strongly recommend you watch the video tutorials. I don't know if they explain exactly this feature, but it's very basic stuff, and you should be able to discover it yourself if you understand the basics